# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException in my netbeans project

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

```
String select = "Select * from subject WHERE subjName=?,userID=?";
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, subjName);
            preparedStatement.setInt(2, id);

            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                qbankID = rs.getInt("qbankID");
            }
```

I have this snippet of my code where the following error appears:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'userID=1' at line 1

I've been stuck here since yesterday and I haven't figured out yet what mistake I was making in my SQL Syntax. Has someone have the same error or do know whats wrong with my code? Will be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't use commas in the `WHERE` clause - use `WHERE subjName=? AND userId=?`

Comment: now im getting errow about the question mark...